# Linq2Sql Contains

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two lists of Data Holders.

```
IQueryable<myClass> aData and IQueryable<myClass> bData
```

Both contain a LocationId
I want to remove all the instances in bData that aren't from Locations in aData. So if location 99 occurs in B but not A, remove it.

So what I did for this is

```
var validLocationIds = aData.Select(d => d.LocationId).Distinct();
var newBData = bData.Where(d=> validLocationIds.Contains(d.LocationId));
```

Then I union the a and newB, group them up and get the values I want.
This works fine some of the time, but for some parameters (used to build A and B)

I get the error message:

> "Method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL."

As soon as I run a `ToList()` after the `Distinct()` to get `ValidLocationId`'s the error message disappears, but I'd like the method to only access the database once.

Am I missing something about the Contains Method here?
(`AData` and `BData` are the same class, and `LocationId` is an int)

Comment: What's the type of `LocationId`?

Comment: @AndrewCoonce it's an int

Comment: Cant you have ValidLocationIds Predicate in Where of bdata?

Comment: Yeah, kostyan just suggested that, but it still gives that error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `d => Contains(d.LocationID)` translates roughly to `d.LocationId IN ( ... )`, which cannot be defined in a single SQL parameter. That means it has the parameters passed into the `IN` clause must be evaluated on the client. This is why it works if you do `.ToList()` to get `validLocationIds`.

If you'd like to do this in a single database query, you can try something like this:

```
var newBData = 
    from b in bData
    join a in aData on b.LocationId equals a.LocationId into ag
    from a in ag.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where a == null
    select b;
```

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of a join, but the removing any from a list of distinct Id's seemed more efficient that joining it all up

Comment: @MikeyMouse Not if you want to do it in a single db query.

Comment: Ok, this works, but man it's so much slower. I haven't run a timer on it yet, but it feels like it's 3x longer. Maybe I'll just stick the ToList() on it, and leave a second database access

Comment: @MikeyMouse I think if your list of candidate `LocationId`'s is small, use `ToList` / `Contains`; if it's quite large, join would probably be faster.

Comment: Yeah, there's only a handful of LocationId's in the query, and usually they're the same this is really just to remove a few that sneak in

Answer (score 1):

can you try following

```
 bData.Where(x => aData.Select(y => y.LocationId).Contains(x.LocationId));
```

Comment: I like that code. Sadly it gives the same error message "Method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL."